# Unknown mediator referenced by configuration element: dataServiceCall

Tags: oracle, service, proxy, wso2

Hi I am trying to use Data Service Call. When I use it in any proxy service in wso2 I get an error Unknown mediator referenced by configuration element: dataServiceCall

> https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/mediators/dss-mediator/

I am following the link as mentioned above. Can someone guide me what am I doing wrong ?

Below is the code I have written

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="TestData" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https local" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <dataServiceCall serviceName="Hello">
            </dataServiceCall>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

[image: Error and service.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this has to do with the version of the `Integration Studio` you are using. It seems the IDE is unable to find the `DataServiceCall Mediator`. First, try updating the Integration Studio referring [this](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/develop/installing-WSO2-Integration-Studio/#get-the-latest-updates) document. If that doesn't work, try using a newer version of the Integration Studio.

Once updated the Dataservicecall Mediator should be listed under the Mediators section.

[image]

Comment: can you provide the link to newest version of Integration Studio ?

Comment: You can download the latest version from here. https://wso2.com/integration/integration-studio/

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a dataservice but you didn't initiate this dataservice project before,so you have to make a dataservice before calling this dataservice from the proxy service.After that a design of "dataServiceCall " will appear in the integration Studio.